# Why is my handheld scanner sending keys in wrong keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I had to replace a computer in a warehouse of ours

in this warehouse, they have QR-Codes which they scan with a handheld bluetooth scanner ([8670 Wireless Ring Scanner](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/products/wearable/8670-ring-scanner)), which is displayed in a self-written program.

The QR-code includes a link - however in the new computer, the link is displayed as `httpsé--` insted of `https://` - all other `/` are also displayed as `-` when the link is scanned.

Why is that? does it have anything to do with language? we're in switzerland and are on `german (swiss)` keyboard layout. `german (germany)` and `french (swiss)` were also installed on the machine, but i changed everything to `german (swiss)` and removed the others but still the link is scanned wrong.

I should also state, that the link is sent to a RemoteApp program, not a program on the computer itself - but the RemoteApp Servers haven't changed and the user also didn't change with which they login to the RemoteApp Server system

what could cause this?

Comment: ok i guess the bluetooth scanner is using US-keyboard-layout - or better said he sends the key from a US-keyboard point of view to a swiss-german-keyboard point of view, because `é` and `-` in swiss-german is where `:` and `/` are located on US-keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as so often - they installed a new handheld-scanner without my knowledge at their workstations.

Handheld scanners need to be configured to the correct keyboard layout.

I had to scan a barcode that set the scanner itself to my preferred keyboard layout.

We also need a carriage return after each scan - i was also able to scan a barcode that made my scanner add a carriage return after each scan.

If you run into the same problem - refer to your scanners Users Guide / Product Guide